# how pass data back from my second view controller to my first view controller using storyboards, or segues, protocols & delegates?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue, navigationcontroller

well is my first post & cannot upload a image because I need a 10 of reputation, XD but it;s ok so:

[image]

Hi Guys, well I need pass a label.text from my cell in my tableview from my second or child view controller, to my first or parent view controller, I want push in a cell & go back with the string to load in the label from my first view controller, I did use a segues from storyboard, I did use a protocols & delegates, but not working, in another questions, the answers or examples are contrary to what I need, or is very different way for xcode version, or how is the best way for to do this?, in the picture I use a button for go to the next view controller for choose the label text that I want in my first view controller, Im using xcode 4.6 & storyboard & ARC too, & some ones lines of code are deprecated, well help me please guys!! & thanks a LOT!!!,

greetings from BOLIVIA!!! n_n'

the code  is like this:

```
     @interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <SecondTableViewControllerDelegate>

    @property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *displayText;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *displayLabel;
    @property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UIButton *Next;

    @end

    @interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize Next;


    -(void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FIRST_TIME"])
        {
            NSLog(@"ES PRIMERA VEZ");
            [Next sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"NO ES PRIMERA VEZ");
        }


    }

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];

        if (self.displayText)
        {
            self.displayLabel.text = self.displayText;
        } else {
            self.displayLabel.text = kDefaultDisplayText;
        }
    }

    #pragma mark - Delegate methods

    - (void)updateText:(NSString *)text {
        self.displayText = text;
    }

    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        if (![segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSecondTableview"]) {
            return;
        }
        /*
        SecondTableViewController *destinationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destinationController.delegate = self;
        destinationController.editText = self.displayText;
        */

        //-- if I pass data from the first view controller to the second right?

    }

    @end

in the second view

    @protocol SecondTableViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

    @optional
    - (void)updateText:(NSString *)text;

    @end

    @interface SecondTableViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

    @property (weak, nonatomic) id<SecondTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
    @property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *editText;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTable;


    @interface SecondTableViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation SecondTableViewController

    -(void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"NO" forKey:@"FIRST_TIME"];

         //---how use the UItable Methods?, how use the protocol method?
    }


    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return self.myArray.count;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myArray";

        myArrayCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        NSDictionary *conjunto = [self.jogArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.myLabel.text = [conjunto objectForKey:@"prueba"];


        return cell;
    }
```

or the protocol delegate must be in the other view controller?, I WANT SHOW IN THE LABEL THE TEXT FROM ANY CELL FROM THE NEXT VIEW CONTROLLER HOW AM I TO DO??

Comment: the problem is like this [link](http://g14.picoodle.com/ltd/img14/5/3/5/dennis_mostajo/f_1nyc_5fb_ud7ko.png)

Comment: I can suggest that you have a look at this answer - although it is not accepted, you can get the delegation idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696304/passing-values-from-second-view-to-firstview-in-xcode EDIT: Another answer which is more detailed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c

Comment: Looks fine so far. You just did not actually call `updateText:`. Setting the delegate is commented out. Why?. That is essential for sending the `updateText:` message to the delegate.

Comment: because that code works if I want pass data from first view controller to the second, but not the second to the first

Comment: Well, that is the point. See my answer. You can use the delegate, which is declared in a protocol, to pass data back to the first view controller. There are more ways for doing so but a delegate, based on a protocol, is a neat and well established solution.

Comment: o well how will be another way to pass back data? to the first viewcontroller without protocol & delegate, exist another method or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the delegate pattern. 
Define a protocol with a method in which the text is handet.

```
- (void) labelText:(NSString*)text;
```

or so. 
Have the partent view controller implementing the protocol. Let's say it is called `YourProtocol`. 
In the child view controler declare a delegate property of type `(id)<YourProtocol>`. 
In the partent view controller assign `self` to `childControler.delegate`. 
When it is about to assign the text then double check whether the delegate conroms to the protocol or responds to the selctor labelText: and then just call it.

Sounds more complext than it really is and it is sort of 'clean'.